# How can I visualize DTI tractography streamlines generated from FSL's probtrackX in 3D?

Tags: computational-modeling, neuroimaging, fmri

I currently have track files of diffusion tensor imaging (DTI) data generated from FSL's probtrackX tractography tool. What is the best software to visualize the streamlines from FSL in 3D?

Comment: I encounter the same problem in visualizing the tractography generated by FSL. I wanna ask do you find an appropriate way to solve the problem. I will appreciate that if you can give me a hint about this. Thank you so much.

Comment: It doesn't generate streamline object as far as I know. I think the best way to visualize them would be to take the fdt_paths.nii file and threshold appropriately. Those are the voxels that streamlines traverse through.

Answer (score 2):

I must say I am not an expert, but the following sources look helpful:

- [Gao *et al*. (2013)](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0075065) write

> The voxel value in the resulting dataset represents the number of
>   streamline samples passing through this voxel times the expected
>   length of these samples. The probabilistic-tractography-derived DDM
>   was generated by keeping the values of those voxels located at the WGM
>   interface and setting the remaining voxels to zero. Again, the DDMs
>   were rendered on the 3D WGM interface in DTI space.

- The **[FDT Userguide](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FDT/UserGuide)** discusses tractography and PROBTRACKX in [**section 2.6.3**](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FDT/UserGuide#Including_targets_for_tractography_-_rationale);
- [Catani & Thiebaut de Schotten (2008)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18619589) discuss how diffusion tensor imaging (DTI) tractography can be used to virtually dissect white matter pathways in the living human brain;
- [This presentation](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fslcourse/lectures/fdt2.pdf) contains a lot of references;
- [Specialist fora like this one](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A2=fsl;cc032134.1304) may be of help.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Catani & Thiebaut de Schotten, *Cortex* (2008); **44**(8):1105-32](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18619589)

**-** [Gao *et al*., *PLoS ONE* (2013); **8**(10): *e75065*](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0075065)</sub>